# How to pass value to model class

Tags: java, spring-mvc

In the jsp page i am using a input field

```
<input type="text"  name="basic" id="basic"  >
```

In controller

```
@RequestMapping(value="/palySlip/add",method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String addData(@ModelAttribute("empPaySlip") EmployeePlaySlip e){

    return "redirect:/employeepayin";
}
```

And value set into a model class

```
 public class EmployeePlaySlip {
    private double basic;
    public double getBasic() {
        return basic;
    }
    public void setBasic(double basic) {
        this.basic = basic;
    }
}
```

But while sending data i got an error

> HTTP Status 400 - type Status report message description The request
>   sent by the client was syntactically incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to have an object set as a model attribute.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/employeepaying",method=RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView showData(){
    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("employeepayingPage");
    mav.addObject(empPaySlip, new EmployeePlaySlip ());
    return mav;
}
```

Add Spring taglib to your `JSP`:

```
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
```

Create form for submition:

```
<form:form method="post"  modelAttribute="empPaySlip" action="/palySlip/add">
    <form:input path="basic" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form:form>
```

Then obtain your model attribute.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/palySlip/add", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String addData(@ModelAttribute("empPaySlip") EmployeePlaySlip e){
    // Do whatever you want with your object
    return "redirect:/employeepaying";
}
```

Comment: you need to mention the name of the model attribute in form tag, <form:form method="post" action="/palySlip/add" modelAttribute="empPaySlip">

Comment: if i am use  private String  basic in model its working , but i want basic as a double

Answer (score 0):

In your @Controller first link your jsp page form with the Model Attribute by Get method

```
@RequestMapping(value= "/studenteducation", method= RequestMethod.GET)
public String setupUpdateEducationForm(Model model,@ModelAttribute("education") Student student){

    student = studentService.getStudent(getStudentName());
    model.addAttribute("education", student);  //adding saved student data into model
    return "studenteducation";
}
```

And one Post method which will submit your jsp form

```
@RequestMapping(value= "/studenteducation", method= RequestMethod.POST)
public String studentEducationForm(Model model, @ModelAttribute("education") Student student, BindingResult result){

    if(result.hasErrors()){
        return "studenteducation";          
    }

    student.setStudentId(getStudentName()); // inserting primary key
    studentService.updateStudent(student);  // updating student table

    return "redirect:/";        
}
```

Note the @ModelAttribute name, It should be same as the jsp modelAttribute name.

Now in jsp page modelAttribute="education" action="/studenteducation" and form inputs with your column name will do the trick.

```
<form:form method="post"  modelAttribute="education" action="/studenteducation">
    <form:input path="your column name" />
    ....
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
```

Comment: With out using this method(<form:input path="your column name" />) can i send directly  <from action='/palySlip/add'><input type="text"  name="basic" id="basic"  ></from>

Comment: Make a default constructor for your model EmployeePlaySlip.